# Specify bean destruction sequence on shutdown

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am currently working on a spring project and I have two beans
Let's say Bean A and Bean B

I want to make sure

1. Bean A is created before Bean B
2. Bean A is destroyed after destroying Bean B

In simple terms, Bean A should exist for the entire lifecycle of Bean B

Is it possible to configure this?

Comment: Look at the @DependsOn annotation

Comment: But that will ensure that Bean A is created after Bean B

Comment: Not if bean B depends on bean A

Comment: Could you point me to the documentation that describes this specific behaviour? because I did try DependsOn annotation but after using it I started getting illegalStateException while running integration tests.

Comment: `@DependsOn` is a terrible solution. You should not interact with infrastructure or other beans when spring is constructing context - you need to wait for `ContextRefreshedEvent` or take advantage of `SmartLifecycle`

Comment: That is already handled by the framework. The destruction is in reverse order of the initialization of beans. So you are trying to solve something that doesn't need to be solved.

Comment: Can Spring detect dependency among beans even if @Autowired is not used ? In my project the dependencies among beans are not too direct so I am wondering if spring can still detect the dependencies. Currently I have a Bean B which uses Bean A. And Bean A is getting destroyed before Bean B

Comment: Bean A is injected (in one form or another) in that bean. Unless you are resorting to ugly hacks with getting beans from the applicaiton context yourself, Spring is perfectly capable of figuring this out by itself.

Comment: Is there any way for me to find out order of destruction of beans on shutdown ? Like something similar to BeanPostProcessor

Answer (score 0):

Please look at below mentioned example, here Class A(Service Bean) will always be created after B as B(repository Bean) available as dependency to A, otherwise it will give exception. After usage of Bean B it will be destroyed as there is not significance in storing it. That is how it is design in Framework itself and it is best approach I cannot think of scenario where it is required.

Even if it is required then check out **Bean Scopes** as this teaches excellent way to define bean life span as per requirement. Please find documentation for [bean scopes](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch04s04.html).

```
 @Service
    public class A{
        private B repository;
        
        @Autowired
        public A(B repository) {
            super();
            this.repository = repository;
        }
    .....//(Rest of code)
    }

    public interface B extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
    .....//Rest of method declaration
    }
```